# cakephp ajax not working properly

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am new in cakephp and I want to implement Ajax on my home page.

I have three modules in my page (client, developer and project). I want to add an ajax link. It's working perfectly only in the index page.

My code:

```
<h2>Projects</h2>
<div class="clear"></div>
<ul>
    <li title="Project List">
        <?php echo $ajax->link('Projects List', array("controller" => "projects", "action" => "index"), array( 'update' => 'main_page' ));?>
    </li><br />
    <li title="Add New Project">
        <?php echo $ajax->link('Add New Project', array("controller" => "projects", "action" => "add"), array( 'update' => 'main_page' ));?>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, my first issue is that in the add form, the validation with js is not working.

Second is: if I use cakephp inbuilt validation then it validates my form but redirects the page to "admin/projects/add" if no data is inserted.

Third problem is that when the above case happens and I want to redirect to listing page through my ajax link, at that time its also not working.

Comment: Show us your controller code. Maybe you have not set up a properly redirection. Concering Ajax: The reason why it works properly on the first page and not on the others is often that the `view` does not contain `<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is stop using the ajax helper. Its been depreciated and will not be available in the 3.x branch.

This was done because it was not a good idea to start with, very limiting and buggy.

ajax with something like jQuery is not very difficult and you should rather look into using that or a similar tool.